# Calling a Jquery Function on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have session variable called page views. When my page is loaded I have a Check to see if it equals 2. IF it does i want to execute code to open a window. Right now i can click a link to open that window and it works fine. How can i get it to automatically open when the page is loaded.

Jquery and Session Checkc code in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<% if (Session["PagesViewed"].ToString() == "2")
   { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
        $('a[name=modal]').click(function (e) {
            //Cancel the link behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            //Get the A tag
            var id = $(this).attr('href');

            //Get the screen height and width
            var maskHeight = $(document).height();
            var maskWidth = $(window).width();

            //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
            $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

            //transition effect     
            $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
            $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

            //Get the window height and width
            var winH = $(window).height();
            var winW = $(window).width();

            //Set the popup window to center
            $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
            $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

            //transition effect
            $(id).fadeIn(2000);

        });

        //if close button is clicked
        $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
            //Cancel the link behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#mask').hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });

        //if mask is clicked
        $('#mask').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });

    });
</script>

<% } %>
```

THis link is used to open the page. But i want to do this automatically when the page is loaded.

```
<a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Window Modal</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$('a[name=modal]').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
```

to

```
        //Get the A tag
        var id = $('a[name=modal]').attr('href');
```

and remove the }); after

```
$(id).fadeIn(2000);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can automatically trigger that anchor's click event:

```
$("a[name='modal']").click();
```

Comment: This is simplest and requires the least amount of changes, but this will also fire any other events attached to that link (click tracking analytics, for example).  If you want to avoid that try my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var openModal = function (e) {
        // Cancel the link behavior if click event
        e && e.preventDefault();

        // Get the A tag or default to modal link href
        var id = $(this).attr('href') || $('a[name=modal]').attr('href');

        // ...REST OF CODE FROM FUNCTION...
    };

    $('a[name=modal]').click(openModal);

    openModal();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put code to load modal window inside `$(document).ready(function () {})`

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
 <% if (Session["PagesViewed"].ToString() == "2")
 { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $('a[name=modal]').attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
        $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

   });
</script>
```